# Whether to include a space after the apostrophe or not

Tags: orthography

I have a very simple question. I would like to know whether when writing Italian it is best to include a space after the apostrophe or not.

Comment: You should never include a space after an apostrophe except cases in which that apostrophe is not an apostrophe but a sign of elision like in *po'*.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider's answer is correct, apart for the fact that an [apostrophe](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apostrofo/) is always an apostrophe, even in *po’*, *mo’* and the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apostrophe must not be followed by a space (and it's better avoiding breaking a line at it, if not under severe constraints like typesetting in narrow columns), *except* in a few cases where, by historical reasons, it marks *troncamento* instead of *elisione*. The cases are

> po’ (poco)
>   mo’ (modo)
>   ca’ (casa)
>   ve’ (vedi)
>   to’ (togli)
>   be’ (bene)

(possibly some others that I can’t remember now).

The last three can be also written *veh*, *toh* and *beh* (see, for instance, [To’ o toh](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/to-o-toh_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)). It would be incorrect writing these words with an accent (but it can be seen, unfortunately).

The apostrophe can be *preceded* by a space, but this is seen only in poetry (where other cases of truncation marked by the apostrophe, so followed by a space can be found, here the reason is metric):

> Allor fu la paura un poco queta
>   che nel lago del cor m'era durata
>   la notte ch’i’ passai con tanta pieta.
>
> E come quei che con lena affannata
>   uscito fuor del pelago a la riva
>   si volge a l’acqua perigliosa e guata,
>
> così l’animo mio, ch’ancor fuggiva,
>   si volse a retro a rimirar lo passo
>   che non lasciò già mai persona viva.
>
> Poi ch’ei posato un poco il corpo lasso,
>   ripresi via per la piaggia diserta,
>   sì che ’l piè fermo sempre era ’l più basso.

(Inferno, canto I, 19–30)

A different case is that of the imperative forms

> da' 
>   di'
>   fa'
>   sta'
>   va'

where the apostrophe actually denotes neither truncation nor elision; these are alternative forms to *dai dici fai stai vai* that developed along with them. The apostrophe here is just an orthographic convention. Also these forms should have a space after them (unless, of course, punctuation follows).

Comment: I guess that, like me, many native speakers will be surprised (to say the least) to learn that _toh_ can also be written _to'_ and stands for _togli_.

Comment: A couple of cases where the space goes before the apostrophe should be added: dialect, like _'namo_ for _annamo_, and numbers, like _'900_ for _1900_ ([source](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/uso-dellapostrofo-forma-ridotta-dellaggettivo))

Comment: Personally, I always am surprised that *toh* is actually admitted by some dictionaries. Every time I read it, it looks like one were to write *un poh*.

Comment: Among the examples of *troncamento*, one might want to add such verbs in the imperative mood as *fa'* and *da'* (not to be confused with the indicative forms *fa* and *dà*).

Comment: @DaG They are not truncations, but independent forms with a parallel development. But you're right, they should be mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. Now you mention it, I seem to remember it was already dealt with somewhere here. When can I find more about it (here or elsewhere)?

Comment: @DaG I seem to remember having commented about it.

Comment: @DaG, il mondo è bello perché è avariato... (Italian learners: usually it's _vario_, not _avariato_)

Comment: Indeed, @WalterTross! :-)